# Test if string contains brackets with integer in it

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to test if a string in javascript contains normal brackets with an integer in it

```
var str="(12) this is a test";
var pat=/(([\d]+))/;
if (pat.test(str)) 
    alert("true");
```

Works fine, but it also returns true when the string looks like this

```
var str="12) test";
var str="(12 test";
```

which should return false.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Escape brackets with `\`:

```
/\([\d]+\)/.test(str);
```